# conditional Mysql event with two tables

Tags: mysql, events

```
CREATE EVENT myevent4
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' MINUTE
DO
UPDATE receipt r
inner join loan l
on l.l_app_file_id=r.r_app_file_id
SET delinquent = (
    if r.receipt_on='Principal' AND r.receipt amount >= l.app_principal
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0

    END
);
```

I have two tables loan and receipt, I am trying to create an event so that when column receipt_on (from receipt table) is 'Principal' and column receipt_amount(from receipt table) is greater than or equal to column app_principal (from loan table) then set column delinquent (from receipt table) to be 0 else 1.
However there seems to be an error in my event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following

```
CREATE EVENT myevent4
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' MINUTE
DO
UPDATE receipt r
inner join loan l
on l.l_app_file_id=r.r_app_file_id
SET delinquent = (
    case when r.receipt_on='Principal' AND r.receipt amount >= l.app_principal
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0

    END
)
```

Comment: could you take a quick look @ this please Im tryin to merge to events in one similar to the one you answered

Comment: CREATE EVENT myevent6
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' MINUTE
DO
UPDATE receipt r
inner join loan l
on l.l_app_file_id=r.r_app_file_id
SET delinquent3 =( 
    case when r.receipt_on='Quarterly Interest' AND r.receipt_amount >= l.app_quarterly_intrest
    THEN 0
    ELSE 1
END)
 
SET delinquent2= (
 case when r.receipt_on='Principal' AND r.receipt_amount >= l.app_principal
 
 THEN 0
        ELSE 1

    END)

Comment: CREATE EVENT myevent6 ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' MINUTE DO 
UPDATE receipt r inner join loan l on l.l_app_file_id=r.r_app_file_id 
SET delinquent3 =( case when r.receipt_on='Quarterly Interest' 
AND r.receipt_amount >= l.app_quarterly_intrest THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) , 
delinquent2= ( case when r.receipt_on='Principal' AND r.receipt_amount >= l.app_principal THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)

Comment: I was wondering if you could take a look at this question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088948/mysql-event-running-yearly-calculations